# Storing data in user table or a new table?

Tags: mysql, database

What is the most effecient, best and fastest way:
Adding a 'banned(boolean)'-field to the user-table, or
creating a brand new table called 'banned'?

Comment: You should include some more information on what you are trying to achieve with that value, expected load, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your banned users have only this single property (they are banned), then go for a field. For instance, when checking if he/she can access a page, you'll be able to do something like this (in PHP):

```
if ($f['banned']) {
    die("Get out of here, you're banned!");
} else {
    // Your logic for normal, i.e., non-banned users
}
```

where `$f` is the array returned by PDO's `fetch()` or an equivalent function.
If, however, you need some special processing for banned users (logging their IPs — and only their ones — or, for example, counting their trials to access your website) that would involve other data, then go for a table which should obviously contain a `UserId` field to have a relation to the main users table. Then you'll need to join this table in each query when checking a user.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Actually I want only store the reason why the user got banned. So in fact 2 fields: isBanned and reasonBanned